# On the optimization of logic circuits

Tags: digital-logic

I am studying an intro to digital logic textbook and, as is standard, optimization techniques are being introduced to simplify the canonical sum-of-products (SOP) and product-of-sums (POS) forms. However, I am wondering if there are any general statements that can be made about two-level circuits (as in SOP or POS) versus multi-level (>=3) circuits as it pertains to cost. I think it unlikely, but is there any general theorem saying that one will have lower cost than the other (defining cost, say, as the number of gates in the circuit plus the number of inputs to each gate)?

Comment: I am not aware of any such theorem.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is define **cost**. Is it just monetary, or do you also care about power and delay?

Comment: In general, neither canonical POS nor SOP are "optimal" in terms of the gates number.

Comment: [I think I answered this here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/165248/question-about-logic-gate-optimization-and-cmos-implementations/654058#654058) My understanding is that factorization is heuristic even simply optimizing for the minimal number of FETs.